# Working with Collections in JAVA

Tags: java, collections

There are two classes

***first class is***

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import java.util.Collections;

public class Hieracrhy  
{

    ArrayList<Tutor> Tutor_person=new ArrayList<Tutor>();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Hieracrhy obj=new Hieracrhy();
        obj.start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        getDetails();
        System.out.println(Tutor_person);
    }

    //Function to read the songs from the file
    void getDetails()
    {
        try 
        {
            File file=new File("SongsList.txt");//Represents a file
            FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(file);//FileReader connects to a text file
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);//For Efficient reading of file

            // We use String variable to hold each line when the line is read one-by-one
            String line=null;

            //Read a line of the string and assign it to a string if it is not null just  doo the func
            while((line=reader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                addDetails(line);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void addDetails(String lineToParse)
    {
        String[] tokens=lineToParse.split("/");
        Tutor nextPerson=new Tutor(tokens[0]);
        Tutor_person.add(nextPerson);
    }
}
```

***Now there is another class***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Tutor 

{

    int Tutor_id;
    String Tutor_name;
    String Tutor_place;
    int Tutor_age;

    public void Set_Things_for_Tutor(int Tutor_id,String Tutor_name,String Tutor_place,int Tutor_age)
    {
        this.Tutor_id=Tutor_id;
        this.Tutor_name=Tutor_name;
        this.Tutor_place=Tutor_place;
        this.Tutor_age=Tutor_age;

    }

    public int getuserid()
    {
        return Tutor_id;
    }
    public String getname()
    {
        return Tutor_name;
    }
    public String getdesignation()
    {
        return Tutor_place;
    }
    public int getage()
    {
        return Tutor_age;
    }
}
```

Now there are inputs in a text file

```
11/devrath/hassan/22
```

but when i run the complete setup im getting the error

> constructor tutor(string) is undefined

What is the reason for this error ..... can someone help me with a good i/p on this

Thanks

Comment: to split line on "/" you have to use split("//");

Comment: Please respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @AchintyaJha not really '/' isnt a meta character. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html

Comment: Java people would be happy to see Java naming convention.

Comment: @Devrath : you might wanna edit the title according to your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not defined any constructor with "String" parameternthe JVM is unable to find it.

Define the constructor as follows:

```
public Tutor(String name)
{
     //Do required initialization here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> constructor tutor(string) is undefined

The error says it all.There is no constructor in your **Tutor class** which accepts string as an argument.

```
public Tutor {
//instance vars

public Tutor(String s){
//assign s to appropriate member variable
}

}
```

Btw, the design of the Tutor class seems bad. you initialize you instance members in your constructor(which ther are meant to do). you are currently initializing Tutor state in a method. i'd advice you to initialize them in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you have to rename `Set_Things_for_Tutor` to `Tutor` in your `Tutor` class. And remove the `void` string.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Tutor` class does not have a constructor that accepts String as its parameter. if you want to pass a String in your `Tutor` class then add this to your code

```
public class Tutor{
  //Other member variables
  public Tutor(String yourString){
     //Do some initializations
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you create an instance of a class , the constructor is called

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

this calls the default constructor

```
public MyClass(){}
```

but since you haven't made any parameterized consstructor
then JVM itself creates it for you

but if you want to pass some parameter to the constructor

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(someInteger,someString);
```

in this case , JVM doent create any default constructor as you already have created a parameterized constructor

```
public MyCLass(int someInteger,String someString){}
```

in your case , you have not made any constructor ,
thus JVM only creates the default constructor

```
public MyClass(){}
```

so all you have is a non parameterized constructor
but what you are trying to access is a parameterized constructor

so all you have to do is to create a parameterized constructor in the class whose object are you creating ...

in your case

```
public Tutor(String string) {
    System.out.println("add the code to initialize the class parameters here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you calling code has one argument constructor and called code (Tutor) class doesn't have one argument constructor.

add constructor

```
public Tutor (String str)
{
     //do your initialization here about 'str' variable.
}
```